# mysql query IF?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT sum(table2.count+table1.count) 
FROM table1,table2
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table2.kind=table3.kind
WHERE table1.user='test' AND table2.user='test' AND table3.kind=1;
```

I am trying to sum table1 and table2 'count'. If table2 has a matching row, then 'kind' must match 'kind' on table 3.

Table 1 will always be counted, but there may not be matching rows in table2. - **that is currently the problem**. It works fine if both tables have the rows.

How could I make summing table2's results optional (if no matches are found)?

Answer (score 0):

`COALESCE(table2.count, 0)` avoids the value passed to `sum()` from nulling out, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not sure if I am asking that. I just want the query to work even if there are no matching rows in table2 (and just count table2.count).